# Elasticsearch - encryption at rest

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am trying to encrypt elasticsearch indexes at rest.It looks ES tores lucene blocks .fdt files which are easily readable.

It seems ES support dm-crypt/LUKS but I dont find any documentation about how to set up the handshake between ES and dm-crypt.

has anyone successfully encrypted ES data at rest?

Comment: did you find the solution for this problem, if yes can you please post your answer. It would be very helpful